# Swift / iOS / Kanna / parse image from html using xpath

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the [Kanna](https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna) framework to use xpath parsing.
I'm successfully getting text from my desired url using the following code:

```
    @IBAction func getSource(sender: AnyObject) {

    if let doc = Kanna.HTML(url: (NSURL(string: "http://qwertz.com")!), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {


        // Search for nodes by XPath
        for link in doc.xpath(".//*[@id='bday_form']/div[1]/img[1]") {
            print(link.text)
            print(link["href"])

            self.testLabel.text = link.text
        }
    }

    print("test22")

}
```

How can I parse images and put them into my imageView Outlet `@IBOutlet weak var imageViewOutlet: UIImageView!`

Help is very appreciated.

```
self.imageViewOutlet.image = link
```

throws: Cannot assign value of type 'XMLElement' to type 'UIImage?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to download the image before assign to UIImageView. There is really good library to download image from the web. It has swift support also.

Here is :https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Here is an example:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:link]
[self.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:url];
```

Comment: is it possible to find the pictures using css/xpath using this library?

Comment: No, You need to get image url using different library. I think you have already got the url from css/xpath. Just use sdwebImage for downloading image from a url .

Answer (score 1):

you need to download the image from the url first, and then create the UIImage

Here's an example of how to do this
[Loading/Downloading image from URL on Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231680/loading-image-from-url) where the shortest approach (from @Lucas Eduardo) looks like this

```
let url = NSURL(string: image.url)
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
imageURL.image = UIImage(data: data!)
```

Comment: there's a good solution, but it doesn't really fit my needs since I have to get the images using xpath. in the solution I'm only able to find them hard coded

Comment: ok - so it's a two-part question?  how to find all of the images and also how to display them?

Comment: yes. I know I can find them using xpath-contains:"xy". I'm familiar with that in java. but yes. I need to display them into an collectionview.